# quilt: release and debug versions of series file

Tags: quilt

Is there any proper way to apply different series of patches with quilt. I need it for release and debug version of series file. I want to use series.debug or series.release file for debug or for release version of linux kernel accordingly.
Or maybe there is another appropriate way to apply different patches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in quilt man page:

```
quilt recognizes the following variables:  
...  
QUILT_SERIES - The name of the series file, defaulting to "series". 
               Unless an absolute path is used, the search algorithm 
               described above applies.
```